# How to remove extra lines from the command output?

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

The following command outputs 4 lines:

```
PS C:\> &{ py -3 -c "for i in range(2): print(f'{i}\r\n', end='')" ; Write-Output "" ; Write-Output "Done!" }
0
1

Done!
```

I need to process the output (to add some info like timestamp, level, etc.):

```
PS C:\> $c=0 ; &{ py -3 -c "for i in range(2): print(f'{i}\r\n', end='')" ; Write-Output "" ; Write-Output "Done!" } | %{ Write-Host ('{0:d3} : {1}' -f (++$c),$_) }
001 : 0
002 :
003 : 1
004 :
005 :
006 : Done!
```

but there are some extra lines now - 002, 004.

How can I get the following output:

```
001 : 0
002 : 1
003 :
004 : Done!
```

?

External commands (like `py`) inside the script-block `&{ }`maybe mixed with PowerShell commands in arbitrary order.

Comment: Don't use `Write-Host` as it doesn't care about the pipeline.

Comment: It's at the end of pipeline, I need it there.

Comment: It’s common to add | where {$_}  to filter out blank lines

Comment: Your code without `Write-Host` produces 6 lines. So what you are seeing is by design and expected. Each of those 3 "blank" lines has the same output. Since there is no difference, you will have to logically create a difference. I'd either band-aid it like `$c=0; &{ py -3 -c "for i in range(2): print(f'{i}\r\n', end='')" ; Write-Output "<Remove>" ; Write-Output "Done! " } | Where {$_} | %{ Write-Host ('{0:d3} : {1}' -f (++$c),($_ -replace '<Remove>')) }` or just use a different separator strategy.

Comment: Since in Windows the default newline sequence is CRLF, you could just use `&{ py -3 -c "for i in range(2): print(f'{i}\n', end='')" ; Write-Output "" ; Write-Output "Done! " }`. Then you don't have to worry about the lone line feeds being piped as objects.

Comment: `py -3 -c "for ..."` is a mock command. The actual command is a third-party binary that produces a similar output.

Comment: That's fine. Your issue is mixing that command with `Write-Output ""`. Without `Write-Output ""`, then `| Where {$_}` filters out empty lines regardless if they are from called script blocks, external commands, or commandlets. If this doesn't satisfy you, you should rephrase your question. If you are waiting for an all-inclusive answer that says "when using `& { command }` *always* do ***this***," it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
&{ py -3 -c "for i in range(2): print(f'{i}\r', end='')" ; Write-Output "" ; Write-Output "Done!" }
```

So I removed the "\n", because it triggers a new line, but you already triggered a return with "\r".

I get the following output:

```
0
1

Done!
```